# There are how many ways we can access UI components in code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am just trying to figure out how many different methods or ways are out there through which we can access the UI components of the app. As far as I have known yet, there are two.

1. `findViewById()`
2. `getResource().getIdentifier(componentID, "id", getPackageName());`

But I am sure that there will be more. I am just curious to know about them and also the differences between them and which one is preferred to use in certain conditions.

Comment: You can access with `ViewBinding` as well.. But why are you counting them?

Comment: You basically almost never want to do the second.  It exists, but its far less efficient.  There's a limited set of reasons for doing it, pretty much all of which have to deal with building more of a platform than an app.

Comment: @Zain I am just wanted to know to have more stuff in my toolkit.